# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid When delete set column null/any value

Tags: oracle-apex

Can we modify interactive grid such that when we select and delete a row, instead of deleting the entire row, a column of that row gets updated to a particular value?

If it can be done using dynamic actions can you please suggest how?

Ex of my interactive grid-> 
[image]

So when i select the 3 lines next to check box and choose option to delete row, it shows the row as strike off. 
But actually instead of deleting it would set Approver column to 'Not Approver'

Comment: Hi Vini, did you still need help with this or did Chaitanya’s answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do by creating a button and then defining a dynamic action.
1)Set the static ID of your IG
2)Create a button and set it to Defined by Dynamic Action
3)Set the True action to execute Javascript Code. Now, your Javascript code should include to set the value of a column in a record by using the setValue method.